# Program file in Bada Development

Tags: c++, eclipse, bada

When I try to launch my Bada application from the BadaIDE to the simulator is returns and error detailing "A program file was not specified in the launch configuration."

If I go to the launch configuration can't to set my "Code Binary Path:" because if I search for it in the project I won't locate it.

Please I hope I can get the attention of an experienced Bada developer to help me through this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

"Code Binary Path" is available under "Run/Debug settings" if you click on "Edit" while "MyProject Debug - Emulator" is selected.

If you don't have a debug config, do menu/Run/Debug As/bada Emulator. This should create a debug config.

That said, try with a brand new project. Normally a project is set up for emulator launch automagically upon creation.